# assign matched values from jquery regex match to string variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am doing it wrong. I know.

I want to assign the matched text that is the result of a regex to a string var.

basically the regex is supposed to pull out anything in between two colons

so **blah:xx:blahdeeblah** 
would result in **xx**

```
var matchedString= $(current).match('[^.:]+):(.*?):([^.:]+');
alert(matchedString);
```

I am looking to get this to put the xx in my matchedString variable.

I checked the jquery docs and they say that match should return an array. (string char array?)

When I run this nothing happens, No errors in the console but I tested the regex and it works outside of js. I am starting to think I am just doing the regex wrong or I am completely not getting how the match function works altogether

Comment: This looks like a syntax error - there is an unopened closing parenthesis in your regex as well as an unclosed opening parenthesis. Is your code displayed correctly?

Comment: The regex was wrong to begin with. [^.:]+:(.*?):[^.:]+ would have been correct. It was also even more wrong because my strings in reality were blah:blahblah:xx:blahdeeblah  so it wouldn't have matched what I wanted. The split function did the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I checked the jquery docs and they say that match should return an array.

No such method exists for jQuery.  `match` is a standard javascript method of a string.  So using your example, this might be

```
var str = "blah:xx:blahdeeblah";
var matchedString = str.match(/([^.:]+):(.*?):([^.:]+)/);
alert(matchedString[2]);
// -> "xx"
```

However, you really don't need a regular expression for this.  You can use another string method, `split()` to divide the string into an array of strings using a separator:

```
var str = "blah:xx:blahdeeblah";
var matchedString = str.split(":");  // split on the : character
alert(matchedString[1]);
// -> "xx"
```

- [String.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Objects:String:match)
- [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Objects:String:split)

Comment: Even better. Thanks Andy!  Now I fully understand split